# Не могу понять как передаются аргументы

Tags: javascript

Изучаю javascript. Есть код

```
function delay(f, time){
  //alert(arguments);
  for(vs of arguments){
    alert(vs);
  }

  return function(){
      setTimeout(() => {
      f.apply(this, arguments);
  }, time);
  }

}

function f(x) {
  alert( x );
}

var f1000 = delay(f, 1000);
var f1500 = delay(f, 1500);

f1000("тест"); // выведет "тест" через 1000 миллисекунд
f1500("тест2"); // выведет "тест2" через 1500 миллисекунд
```

Не могу понять как аргументы функции f (в данном случае аргумент x, который принимает значения "тест" и "тест2") передаются в функцию delay и функция delay получает к ним доступ... Ведь arguments в функции delay содержат именно аргументы функции delay! А мы как по волшебству в функции delay получаем доступ к аргументам другой функции (в данном случае - к аргументам другой функции f).

Сделал перебор массива arguments, там как и ожидалось в первом элементе

```
function f(x) {
  alert( x );
}
```

во втором задержка 1000 или 1500

Как нам удается пробросить параметр x функции f в f.apply(this, arguments) не пониаю...

Answer (score 1):

*Тут главное - не использовать слово "пробросить".*

---

Коллекции `arguments` в функции `delay` и в возвращаемой анонимной функции - это совершенно разные коллекции.

```
  ...
  return function(){
    setTimeout(() => {
      f.apply(this, arguments);
    }, time);
  }
}
```

Экземпляры этой возвращаемой анонимной функции присваиваются переменным `f1000` и `f1500`.

Для `f1000` - значение `time` равно `1000`.
Для `f1500` - значение `time` равно `1500`.

`f` в обоих случаях - внешняя функция `f` - первый параметр в вызовах `delay`.

У стрелочной функции, которая является первым параметром `setTimeout`, своих `arguments` нет, она использует `arguments` той функции, внутри которой она определена, то есть `f1000` или `f1500`.

А аргументы этих `f1000` и `f1500` - `"тест"` и `"тест2"` соответственно.